# Unable to match tuples items to list items

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a list (tags) of integers. I want to map the list items to the value items of a dictionary (classes) and get the corresponding dictionary keys as output.

I am using:

```
h = classes.items()
for x in tags:
    for e in h:
        # print x, e,  # uncomment this line to make a diagnosis
        if x == e[1]:
            print e[0]
        else:
            print "No Match"
```

`Classes` is the dictionary.
`Tags` is the list with items that I want to map with the classes. When I run this code, I am getting 2616 time `No Match` at the output.

```
2616 = 8 (no. of tuples)*327 (no. of items of tags list)
```

Comment: Try adding a line with print x,e, before your if statement. This will help you understand why the comparison is not working. You may want to share an extract of your output here in order to get help.

Comment: Can you post samples of `class.items()` and `tags` ?

Comment: @gauden
Sir i am getting:

   liverpool@gandalf:~/rise/rise$ python test.py
   7
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 57, in <module>
        print x, e
    NameError: name 'e' is not defined

which makes sense because the variable e is initiated inside second 'for' loop.

Comment: Do you really want to maps the tags to the dictionary keys and maybe store that to some object, or do you want to just print them?

Comment: @IronFist
sample data:

class.items() = [('Ford', 1), ('Nissan', 0), ('Mazda', 4), ('Ferrari', 2), ('Suzuki', 3), ('Honda', 5), ('Toyota', 6), ('Tesla', 7)]

tags = ['0','2','1','3','4','7','2','0','1','6','3','2','8','4','1','2','0','7','5','4','1']

Comment: @Reti43
I want the tags to be mapped to dictionary items because I need the dictionary data for later use in the program. I am printing it out here just to verify that it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do maybe this will help

```
>>> tags
['0', '2', '1', '3', '4', '7', '2', '0', '1', '6', '3', '2', '8', '4', '1', '2', '0', '7', '5', '4', '1']
>>> classes
{'Tesla': 7, 'Nissan': 0, 'Honda': 5, 'Toyota': 6, 'Ford': 1, 'Mazda': 4, 'Ferrari': 2, 'Suzuki': 3}
```

`tags` is a list of strings, not integers - so let's convert it to a list of ints.

```
>>> tags = map(int, tags)
```

`classes` is a dictionary mapping car makes to ints, but we want to use the value as the lookup.  We can invert the dictionary (swap keys and values)

```
>>> classes_inverse = {v: k for k, v in classes.items()}
```

Now this is what `tags` and `classes_inverse` look like

```
>>> tags
[0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 2, 0, 1, 6, 3, 2, 8, 4, 1, 2, 0, 7, 5, 4, 1]
>>> classes_inverse
{0: 'Nissan', 1: 'Ford', 2: 'Ferrari', 3: 'Suzuki', 4: 'Mazda', 5: 'Honda', 6: 'Toyota', 7: 'Tesla'}
```

Now we can collect the values of the inverse dictionary for each item in the list.

```
>>> [classes_inverse.get(t, "No Match") for t in tags]
['Nissan', 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'Suzuki', 'Mazda', 'Tesla', 'Ferrari', 'Nissan', 'Ford', 'Toyota', 'Suzuki', 'Ferrari', 'No Match', 'Mazda', 'Ford', 'Ferrari', 'Nissan', 'Tesla', 'Honda', 'Mazda', 'Ford']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 
The problem was with the `tags` being a list of strings while I was comparing strings with integers in the for loop. Thanks a zillion of the `map` function. It worked like a charm after conversion.

Answer (score 0):

For each tag, you iterate through all the keys, and print whether it was a match or not, when you except to have at most one hit. For example, if you have 10 items, for each tag, you'll print 1 hit and 9 misses.

Since you want to store this data, the easiest way is to invert the dictionary map, i.e. make key -> value to value -> key. However, this assumes that all values are unique, which your example implies so.

```
def map_tags(tags, classes):
    tag_map = {value: key for key, value in classes.items()}
    return [tag_map.get(t, 'No match') for t in tags]
```

However, be careful. In your `classes` examples the values are integers, while the tags are strings. You want the two to match when making a map out of them. If the tags are intended to be strings, then change

```
tag_map.get(t, 'No match')
```

to

```
tag_map.get(int(t), 'No match')
```